# How to pull a dynamic/rolling date range in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I want to subset my data to where my data frame only contains observations dated up to 30 days ago.  The goal is to pull 30 days sales every time I run the script with each new day and run an analysis on that information. The date range column initially loads in as UNIX time, but I also have a script that can convert it to a date format. Maybe I should set up a script to exclude date ranges past a certain time frame before the date gets converted out of UNIX time?

`as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$order_timestamp, origin="1970-01-01"))`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers you question on how to filter/work with unix filtering for last 30 days in some data

```
# dummy with date and unix values
df <- data.frame(ts_date = as.Date(c("2021-05-31","2021-06-30","2021-07-31")),
                 ts_unix = c(1622425615,1625017615,1627696015),
                 v = c(123, 456, 789))

# used recent unix ts (you could use as.numeric(Sys.time())
end <- as.Date(1627348803/(60*60*24), origin="1970-01-01")
start <- end - 30

# one option to filter data of last thiry
df[df$ts_date >= start & df$ts_date < end,]

     ts_date    ts_unix   v
2 2021-06-30 1625017615 456


library(dplyr)

# dplyr option to filter
df %>%
      dplyr::filter(ts_date >= start & ts_date < end)

     ts_date    ts_unix   v
1 2021-06-30 1625017615 456

# dplyr option to filter and using current unix
df %>%
      dplyr::filter(ts_unix > as.numeric(Sys.time()) - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60)

     ts_date    ts_unix   v
1 2021-06-30 1625017615 456
2 2021-07-31 1627696015 789

# set up date range
seq(start, end-1, 1)
[1] "2021-06-27" "2021-06-28" "2021-06-29" "2021-06-30" "2021-07-01"
[6] "2021-07-02" "2021-07-03" "2021-07-04" "2021-07-05" "2021-07-06"
[11] "2021-07-07" "2021-07-08" "2021-07-09" "2021-07-10" "2021-07-11"
[16] "2021-07-12" "2021-07-13" "2021-07-14" "2021-07-15" "2021-07-16"
[21] "2021-07-17" "2021-07-18" "2021-07-19" "2021-07-20" "2021-07-21"
[26] "2021-07-22" "2021-07-23" "2021-07-24" "2021-07-25" "2021-07-26"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, exactly what I was trying to figure out! It makes sense how you set up the end and start times. seems like it's pretty intuitive to manipulate UNIX time if you set it up correctly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RyanKapsak plz consider to acept or upvote my answer for others to know it has been solved. thx

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have 15 reputation yet :[